# How to create links between XML files

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XML file "tasks.xml" which contains references to the resource tags :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config_data>
<resources>
    <resource name="FRED" />
    <resource name="JOHN" />
</resources>

<type_of_task>
    <name>TASK1</name>
    <uses>
        <resource refName="FRED" />
    </uses>
</type_of_task>

<type_of_action>
    <name>ACTION1</name>
    <uses>
        <resource refName="FRED" />
    </uses>
</type_of_action>

</config_data>
```

and corresponding "tasks.xsd" file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="config_data">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
         
            <xs:element name="resources">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element name="resource" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType>
                           <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:ID" use="optional" />
                        </xs:complexType>
                     </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            
            <xs:element name="type_of_task">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name" />
                     <xs:element name="uses">
                        <xs:complexType>
                           <xs:sequence>
                              <xs:element name="resource">
                                 <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="refName" type="xs:IDREF" />
                                 </xs:complexType>
                              </xs:element>
                           </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                     </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>

            <xs:element name="type_of_action">
               <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                     <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name" />
                     <xs:element name="uses">
                        <xs:complexType>
                           <xs:sequence>
                              <xs:element name="resource">
                                 <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:attribute name="refName" type="xs:IDREF" />
                                 </xs:complexType>
                              </xs:element>
                           </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                     </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
               </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But I want to split the XML file into 2 files - tasks1.xml containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config_data>

<resources>
    <resource name="FRED" />
    <resource name="JOHN" />
</resources>

</config_data>
```

and tasks2.xml containing

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config_data>

<type_of_task>
    <name>TASK1</name>
    <uses>
        <resource refName="FRED" />
    </uses>
</type_of_task>

<type_of_action>
    <name>ACTION1</name>
    <uses>
        <resource refName="FRED" />
    </uses>
</type_of_action>

</config_data>
```

How do I reference the first XML file from the second XML file and what are the 2 corresponding XSD files ?

Comment: Upvote to zero was made because this is a new contributor. A hint on the question: XML files are for data storage, not processing. There is no preset referencing scheme between XML files, this is a problem to solve with processing. However, you are free to define your own referencing data, but can't expect this to be processed unless you set up processing it. How is your data processed?

Comment: Why do you want to split up your (small) XML document? Why do you think XSDs are part of the solution (or do you just want us to write the XSDs for you)?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It was a simple example because I wanted to understand the principle of how you do it so that I could apply it to more complex examples.  In the example above tasks2.xml would change more frequently than tasks1.xml. The idea was that if I changed 'refName="FRED"' to 'refName="FRED1" then I would get a validation error when checked against the XSD. I was wondering if something like xpointer could be used but I am not sure. Any helpful ideas would be much appreciated.